# Android Marshmallow uses permissions migration

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to follow the guide from google to implements permissions in my app to work with `Android M`. ( http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html )
However, I am NOT able to check the `<uses-permission>`, my questions is: should I migrate the `<uses-permission>` into `<permission>` ?

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

My manifest permissions are this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

To be more explicit I am able to call only this method:

```
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL);
```

I can't check the `internet`, `wake_lock` or other `<uses-permission>`

Comment: "However, I am NOT able to check the <uses-permission>" -- please explain what you mean by this. "should I migrate the <uses-permission> into <permission> ?" -- no. Get rid of `<permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />` (as that is not your permission to define, since [it already exists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL)). At most, have a `<uses-permission>` for that.

Comment: I need to use `<uses-permission-sdk-23` for marshmallow ?

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't check the internet, wake_lock or other

That is because those are not `dangerous` permissions. The `dangerous` permissions, for Android 6.0, are:

- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
- `ADD_VOICEMAIL`
- `BODY_SENSORS`
- `CALL_PHONE`
- `CAMERA`
- `GET_ACCOUNTS`
- `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`
- `READ_CALENDAR`
- `READ_CALL_LOG`
- `READ_CELL_BROADCASTS`
- `READ_CONTACTS`
- `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- `READ_PHONE_STATE`
- `READ_SMS`
- `RECEIVE_MMS`
- `RECEIVE_SMS`
- `RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH`
- `RECORD_AUDIO`
- `SEND_SMS`
- `USE_SIP`
- `WRITE_CALENDAR`
- `WRITE_CALL_LOG`
- `WRITE_CONTACTS`
- `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

You get `normal` permissions, like `WAKE_LOCK` and `INTERNET`, automatically. `MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL` is a `signature`-level permission; ordinary Android apps cannot hold it.

> I need to use `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` for marshmallow ?

That is for permissions that you *only* want to request on API Level 23+ devices, but want to skip on older devices.

> should I migrate the `<uses-permission>` into `<permission>` ?

No. The framework defines the framework permissions. You would use `<permission>` only if you are defining some custom permission for use by third-party clients of your app's API.

Comment: Dangerous permissions are declared in manifest in the same way as normal permissions ?

Comment: @PavelMarian: In terms of `<uses-permission>`, yes. Whoever *defines* the permission, via the `<permission>` element, will have an `android:protectionLevel` attribute with `normal`, `dangerous`, `signature`, etc. Permissions that you see in the Android SDK are defined by the framework.